# Node, XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I'm a bit new to Node.  I am trying to simply fire a function that will do an XHR to a node route.  In the route I am just logging some formData to the NODE console.

api.js

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
var uploadApi = {
  uploadFiles: function(files, url, directory){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('greeting', 'hello');
    form.append('whyme', {'hello':'hi');
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload' ,true);
   xhr.send(form);
  }
};

module.exports = uploadApi;
```

node route /upload

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/upload', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);  //<----comes up empty
});
```

for some reason the req.body is not showing an data. It shows a blank {}.  Please help.  This just feels like such a foolish problem to have.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost definitely your body parser. My untested suggestion is to try

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false,
      type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}));
```

on your server, and

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

On your client

You can investigate the full set of options here:
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions